# How to make a sliding thingamajig between photos?

Tags: javascript, jquery

See the effect in the photos in the article here:

http://www.popsci.com/science/article/2012-11/and-after-images-show-hurricane-sandys-devastation

Does anyone have any idea how that's done? I suppose I could make two frames with adjustable width within a fixed frame, but what about the handle? And the way the frame line and handle brighten and enlarge when you mouse over? Hover event, to be sure, but what kind of hover event?

Comment: For the brightening, just use CSS `:hover`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple. You have 2 `DIV`s with the 2 different images (as `background-image` in css) overlapping eachother (In e.g absolute positioning.) (Perhaps the "Before" picture above)
Then you have a slider and when dragged it decreases the overlapping `DIV`'s width, making the underlaying DIV show!
This functionallity can be found in a jQuery plugin called "Before/After"

Link: [jQuery BEFORE / AFTER](http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/06/25/jquery-beforeafter-plugin/)

Comment: But how did they put the pretty handle on the slider, with the arrows?

Comment: @Aerovistae That's all generated with the jQuery plugin! :)

Comment: Yes, I guess I mean how did the plugin author do it? If you know offhand what sort of thing you mess with to achieve that sort of effect. I'm just not expert enough with jQuery to know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could of course just write your own that isn't dependant on jQuery UI.

```
;(function($){
    $.fn.slidingThingamajig = function () {

        return this.each(function(){

            var $this = $(this);

            $this.find('.handle')
                 .css({cursor:'ew-resize'}) // Here's your fancy cursor with directional arrows
                 .on('mousedown', function(e) {
                     $this.addClass('resizable');

                     $this.parents().on('mousemove', function (e) {
                         $('.resizable').css({width:e.pageX - $('.resizable').offset().left});
                     }).on('mouseup', function(e) {
                         $('.resizable').removeClass('resizable');
                 });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

You would probably need to tweak this a little, but it's mostly all there.